# No body in ResponseEntity when using spring annotation @ResponseStatus

Tags: spring, rest

I have an endpoint who throw an Exception using spring annotation, here is the code of my Exception :

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class MyException extends BaseApiException{

public MyException (String variable){

super("variable :"+variable+" can not be updated.");
}
}
```

When i use postman to test the Rest endpoint i get a correct result with a correct status code :

```
{
"errorType": "MyExption",
"message": "variable : XYZ can not be updated."
}
```

My problem is when i try to call the service using restTemplate I did not receive a body in the response, here is my code :

```
ResponseEntity<Document> response;
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, Document.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define an error handler to extract this

```
public class MyResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyResponseErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        //here you should be able to get //response.getBody()   
        log.error("Response error: {} {}", response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusText());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return isError(response.getStatusCode());
    }

    public static boolean isError(HttpStatus status) {
        HttpStatus.Series series = status.series();
    return (HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR.equals(series)
            || HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR.equals(series));
   }


}


RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.setErrorHandler(new MyResponseErrorHandler());
```